# How to remove certain warning text from input value only when user starts typing in the input field?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I have a value being php echoed in an input field after a form validation like so:

```
x - Confirm valid surname
```

What code (Javascript only) is appropriate to use if I want to remove the matching text `" - Confirm valid surname"` (this would be a warning message) when user starts typing inside the input field (ideally when changing to a valid surname) ?

Comment: Why not just use the placeholder attribute?

Comment: How would that solve it ? The placeholder is already in use with instruction to Enter surname

Comment: And how would anyone know that since a) you didn't say that or b) post a [mcve]

Comment: right. I guess an example would be more appropriate. I don't have the energy to offer that now I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your "input" be like this?

`<input value="<?php echo $errorMessage; ?>"/>`

I advise to use the "placeholder" attribute,

```html
<input placeholder="<?php echo $errorMessage; ?>"/>
```

or if you want to keep using JS,

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById(INPUT_BOX_ID);
inputBox.oninput = function(){
    inputBox.value = inputBox.value.replace(" - Confrim valid surname",""); // Simply remove the Error Text you've echoed
    inputBox.oninput = null; //  Delete the function so user can type something
}
// Its still not detecting the valid surname, but its removes the " - Confrim valid surname"
```

Comment: This works ! It turns out that I needed this happening on focus since the user might go to that input and decide to focusout and go to another input field. I changed the "inputBox.oninput" to "inputBox.onfocust" and it works.